# Given the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}+a(t)y=f(t)$ , show that every solution tends to 0 as t approaches infinity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}+a(t)y=f(t)$

with a(t) and f(t) continuous for:

$-\infty<t<\infty$

$a(t) \ge c>0$

$lim_{t_->0}f(t)=0$

Show that every solution tends to 0 as t approaches infinity.

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+a(t)y=f(t)$$

$$μ(t)=e^{\int a(t)dt}$$
$$μ(t)=e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}$$

Multiplying both sides of the equation by $μ(t)$:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+a(t)y=f(t)$$ 
$$μ(t)[\frac{dy}{dt}+a(t)y]=μ(t)[f(t)]$$ 
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}[\frac{dy}{dt}+a(t)y]=e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}[f(t)]$$ 
$$\frac{d}{dt}e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}y=e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}[f(t)]$$ 
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}y=\int e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}[f(t)]dt$$

Did I make a mistake in the integrating factor step? I am not sure how to proceed..

Comment: There is a mistake here: $\int a(t) dt \not = \frac{a^2(t)}{2}$ (unless $a(t) = t$)

Comment: Thats what I thought...I guess I''m not really sure what it would be?

Comment: @MathMajor, just change it to a definite integral. something like $\int_0^t a(s) \, ds$

Comment: To solve the problem [Gronwall's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality) might come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

I will give a solution for the case $f \geq 0$. First we note that the solution can be written (since $y'+ay = f \implies (ye^{\mu})' = fe^{\mu}$ and $y(0)=0$)

$$y(t) = \int_0^t f(t')e^{\mu(t')-\mu(t)} dt'$$

where $\mu(t) = \int_0^t a(t')dt'$. This shows that $y(t)\geq 0$ for all $t\geq 0$. Now using $a(t)\geq c > 0$ we find

$$\mu(t) =  \int_{0}^t a(t')dt' \geq ct$$

Using this we can write the ODE as

$$y' = f - ay \leq f - ct y$$

and apply [Gronwall's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality) to get

$$y(t) \leq \left(\int_0^t f(t')dt'\right)e^{\int_0^t (-ct')dt'} = \left(\int_0^t f(t')dt'\right) e^{-ct^2/2}$$

Since $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{t\to \infty} f(t) = 0$ we have that $f$ is bounded (by $M$) on $\mathbb{R}$ and it follows that

$$0 \leq \lim_{t\to\infty}y(t) \leq \lim_{t\to\infty}Mt e^{-ct^2/2} = 0$$

Comment: Could you please how you applied Grönwall's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

here is way to do this. we will set the lower arbitrarily to $t_0.$ you can change it to anything more convenient if you like. suppose 
$$A = exp\left(\int_{t_0}^t a(s)\,ds\right), \dfrac{1}{A}= exp\left(-\int_{t_0}^t a(s)\,ds\right)$$ is the unique solution of $$ \frac{dA}{dt} - aA = 0, \, A(t_0) = 1.$$  $A$ is called the integrating factor because if you multiply $\frac{dy}{dt} + ay = f$ by $A$ you get $$\dfrac{d}{dt}(Ay)  = Af$$ which can be integrated to give a particular solution 
$$y_P =  \dfrac{1}{A(t)}\left(\int_{t_0}^t A(s)f(s)\,ds\right) = \int_{t_0}^t exp\left(-\int_s^t a(u)\,du\right)f(s)\,ds$$

we will show that $y_P(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty.$

$$ |y_P| \le \int_{t_0}^t exp\left(-\int_s^t a(u)\,du\right)|f(s)|\,ds 
\le \int_{t_0}^t exp\left(-\int_s^t c\,du\right)|f(s)| \,ds$$
picking $t_0$ large enough to make $|f|$ small so that the limit of $y_P$ is zero as $t \to \infty.$

there must be a cleaner way to show that the limit is zero than the one i have here. i will think about it.

Answer (score 0):

After your last step:

$$e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}y=\int e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}[f(t)]dt$$

You want to divide both sides by $e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}$ to solve for $y$

Giving us:

$$y=e^{-\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}\int e^{\frac{1}{2}a^2(t)}[f(t)]dt$$

Comment: But I don't think I correctly integrated a(t) did I?

Comment: Oh yeah you didnt so I guess we have to substitute $\frac{a^2(t)}{2}$ with $A(t)$ where $A(t)$ is the anti-derivative of $a(t)$